# Defining dependency between custom commands in different directories

Tags: cmake, cmake-custom-command

I have a project in which the output of one custom command is used as the input to another, but in a different directory. So for example:

Directory `lib/CMakeLists.txt` contains:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT libfoo.xx
    COMMAND <command to build libfoo.xx>
)
add_custom_target(libfoo DEPENDS libfoo.xx)
```

Directory `test/CMakeLists.txt` contains:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT test.yy
   COMMAND <command to build test.yy>
   DEPENDS "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib/libfoo.xx"
)
```

So I need to make sure that libfoo is build before test.yy. The docs say that the DEPENDS clause of add_custom_command() can only have file-level dependencies. Let's try that and see what happens:

```
No rule to make target 'lib/libfoo.xx', needed by 'test/test.yy'.  Stop.
```

If on the other hand, I attempt to create a target-level dependency by saying `DEPENDS libfoo`, then the error changes to:

```
No rule to make target 'libfoo', needed by 'test/test.yy'.  Stop.
```

So it seems neither file-level or target-level dependencies will work here. Is there any way to have the output from one custom command be the input to another custom command, in a different directory?

Comment: Is there an outermost CMakeLists.txt file which adds both the lib and the test directory with add_subdirectory?

Answer (score 0):

You could try in `test/CMakLists.txt` to add

```
add_custom_target(test DEPENDS test.yy)
```

and then to add

```
add_dependencies(test libfoo)
```

in your top-level `CMakeLists.txt`.

*Disclaimer:* I didn't test it and I'm a CMake beginner. Tell us if it works!